# Getting list element's Attribute

Tags: python

I have two list.
List1 contain objects and each object has node1 property.
List2 contain lists of node which are the properties of objects stored in list1.

I want to create separate list which contain list of objects whose node present in list2. I want to create this list without using for loop because my object list is large so code takes long time to run if I use for loop.

How can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's time to redesign your program. Replace list 2 with a `defaultdict(None)` mapping the objects in list 1 to their node properties. Call it `node` so you can get the node of an object `x` with `node[x]`. You can get the list of all nodes (unordered) with `node.values()` in O(*m*) time where *m* is the number of objects that have an associated node.

(Alternatively, store a `node` attribute in the objects with `None` indicating no node and get the nodes with `[x.node for x in list1 if x.node is not None]`; this takes O(*n*) time but may be faster than a `for` loop.)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no other way than by using a `for` loop:

```
final_list = []
for obj in list1:
    if obj.node1 in list2:
        final_list.append(obj)
```

**EDIT:** 
As for the comments, using a `set` is faster for lookup elements (thanks eumiro):

```
set2 = set(list2)
...
    if obj.node1 in set2:
```

Additionally you can write the code in one line (thanks rocksportrocker):

```
final_list = [obj for obj in list1 if obj not in set2]
```

Comment: You can accelerate the condition by creating a `set2 = set(list2)` before the loop and checking whether `obj.node1 in set2`.

Comment: @eumiro That's the way if you're going to use `list`s; it turns O(m*n) into O(m+n) average, which is the best you can do.

Comment: Writing this as a list comprehension [ obj for obj in list1 if obj not in list2] is less code, but I think not that it is faster

Comment: @rocksportrocker It's probably _very slightly_ faster; there is some optimization in a list comprehension, but the complexity is what's important for large lists. The `set` is much more important than details of how you structure the loop.